# can we use POSIX sockets in iPhone

Tags: iphone, sockets, posix

Can i use POSIX sockets in iPhone OS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, with a few caveats.
A POSIX socket connect will not turn on the cellular radio, so you may have to use a higher level network protocol to pre-flight any socket connection.
Blocking read/writes to a socket should be done in a thread other than the main thread unless you want to block the UI of your app.

Answer (score 0):

[iSO Manual Pages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/system/conceptual/manpages_iphoneos/) says that socket system call is available for use. So you can, given that you really want to go down this low level and ready to manage everything.